# How to show value of extra column in sheets query function

Tags: google-sheets

I'm Query newbie and my IQ is just slightly higher than my shoe size so please, help me out.
[boys and points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOeUz.png)
I have a data set on the picture and I need to get the results include the points of the last date as well.
When I select column with the points I need to aggrevate it which I don't want.
The formula looks like this..

```
=QUERY(AF2:AI13;"select AH, max(AG) 
where AH is not null 
group by AH 
order by max(AG) desc")
```

How can I get the points of the last date for each player?
I can feel ma brain melting.......
Cheers
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using [sortn](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)

```
=sortn(sort(AF3:AI13,2,0),9^9,2,3,0)
```

incase you wish to be selective/re-arrange the order of columns then use:

```
=choosecols(sortn(sort(AF3:AI13,2,0),9^9,2,3,0),3,2,4)
```

Comment: Great, that works. Thank you. Is there any chance I can get the lines ordered by the date desc as well?

Comment: I was married to the idea of query, I didn't try anything else. Nice one!

Comment: for final date desc: `=sort(sortn(sort(AF3:AI13,2,0),9^9,2,3,0),2,0)`

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(,UNIQUE(TOCOL(C2:C,1)),LAMBDA(a,x,
VSTACK(a,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B2:D,C2:C=x),1,0),1))
)),"select Col2,Col1,Col3 offset 1",0)
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this one but it says error but I think it's got something to do with the fact that I use european sheets and some of the signs are different. I've changed all the "," to ";" but there might be something else I don't know about. Thanks for the imput anyway! Appreciate it.